# About pig -files argument

Tags: apache-pig

Is there any docs about what dose pig -files argument do?

It seems it's not handled by org.apache.pig.Main

Also pig -cp is to add some jar files into pig classpath. It's also not a standard pig argument.

Can someone please explain how does pig handle these arguments?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just found -files is handled by GenericOptionsParser.